# guava cache cause many threads park

Tags: java, multithreading, guava

I find many  java threads status is 
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)，
the jsatck instruction is  load guava cache.

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000007c0e65bb8> (a com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:445)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:143)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.waitForValue(LocalCache.java:3573)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.waitForLoadingValue(LocalCache.java:2306)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3957)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4875)
```

guava cache config

```
    CacheLoader<K, CacheValue<V>> loader = new CacheLoader<K, CacheValue<V>>() {
        @Override
        public CacheValue<V> load(final K key) throws Exception {
            try {
                return new CacheValue<V>(loadFromRemoting(key));

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LogUtil.warn(LOGGER, ex)
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ListenableFuture<CacheValue<V>> reload(final K key, final CacheValue<V> oldValue)
                throws Exception {
            // asynchronous refresh cache.
            ListenableFutureTask<CacheValue<V>> task = ListenableFutureTask
                    .create(new Callable<CacheValue<V>>() {
                        @Override
                        public CacheValue<V> call() {
                            try

                                return load(key);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                LogUtil.error(LOGGER, e)
                            }

                            return oldValue;
                        }
                    });

            refreshExecutor.submit(task);
            return task;
        }
    };


    loadingCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(20000)
            .refreshAfterWrite(getDuration(), TimeUnit.MINUTES).build(loader);
```

** the jdk version 6

and the guava version  19.0**

any document about gauva cache design or what's the wrong in the code.

Comment: Well if an element is not in the cache, you need to wait until it's loaded. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: the load is async,why wait it's loaded

Comment: What about it is asynchronous?  `load` doesn't look asynchronous.  _Refreshes_ are asynchronous, but initial loads in the Guava cache are synchronous.

Comment: @LouisWasserman any more detail?

Comment: What detail do you want, exactly?  Loading is synchronous in Guava's cache.